# How to change data (can't get row index in data) when user click on row tree or table plugin?

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart, angular-gantt

I use https://github.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt in my project.
I try to write js code for change data when user click on row in side-content tree or table plugin by call form popup or change data inline tree or table plugin. For this purpose I need get row index which user clicked.

Parameters (directiveName, directiveScope, element, iAttrs, controller) have no info about index in $scope.data[index].

How to get var index in code below?

Thanks!

```js
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {      
        $scope.registerApi = function (api) {
        $scope.api = api;
        api.directives.on.new($scope, function (directiveName, directiveScope, element, iAttrs, controller) {
           // if (directiveName === 'ganttTaskContent') {
            element.bind('click', function () {
            console.log(directiveName, directiveScope, element, iAttrs, controller);
             //How to get index variable value when user click on side row in table or tree plugin? 
             var index  = 3;
             $scope.data[index].tasks[0].from= new Date(2018, 9, 1, 8, 0, 0)
             api.data.get()[index ].name="CHANGED";
             api.columns.refresh(); // if no out of range
             api.columns.generate(); // if  out of range
              
            });
          //   }
        });
        }
        }
```

Comment: if change  element.bind('click', function () to  element.bind('click', function (event) then console.log(event) have not index too

Comment: angular-gantt v2.0.0-rc.1